# PLC View Bit of an address

Tags: plc

I am using a Omron PLC and looking at this bit in memory
CIO1767  BIT 14  In binary view

Its either going to be a 1 (on) or 0 (off)

I would like to put in the ladder logic. If this bit is on do ....
But Dont know how to write that bits address.

First do i have to use a compare to see if its 1 or 0 
or 
can i do a normally open and it give me NC if its 0?

Also if unclear, how do i write this bit i was trying CIO1767.14  but that does not seem to work?
thanks
glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, You can use a NO or NC  operation.  For this instance you have to place the operation, then for address just put CIO . Then it will give you another pop up asking for the data or location here you would put 1767.14.  Thats it!